# Mac OS Activity Monitor Data Received whilst abroad

Tags: download

I'm working remotely for a couple of weeks abroad and need to know how much data I am downloading whilst working. I've looked at the stats in Activity Monitor which has given me a figure, but there are no dates as to when this figure started from. At present it says over 6GB, but if this is from midnight until 9am this seems strange and the figures do not seem to add up.
Also are there any other app which can monitor this easier?
thanks for your help
shel

Answer (score 0):

Activity monitor resets its data counters at reboot.
It also does not differentiate between local network traffic & internet traffic, so is generally no use for this task.

I'm afraid software recommendations are off-topic here, but you could try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)